# What is Brioche d'Arquien's timeline in Dog Days?

Tags: dog-days

I'm a bit confused about it, especially the following dates:

- When was the big battle featuring the Demon King and the Hero King (and, apparently, "a young swordsman Hina Maxima")?
- When was Hina knighted in Biscotti?
- When did she meet Yukikaze? Was it before or after she was knighted?
- How old are actually Maxima siblings and Yukikaze?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yukikaze is normal so it should be recent. The rest, I guess, will have to be confirmed with a rewatch.

Comment: @nhahtdh I think in S2E11 they said that Yukikaze spent a lot of time as a kid, before meeting Princess Millhiore and others, and then grew up quickly.